# Checking for a valid delegate object before sending it a message

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, retain

I am trying to implement the delegate Pattern in Objective-C, however I am experiencing a Bad Access exception when invoking the delegate sometimes. It seems this is caused by the delegate being released. Apple does not recommend to retain delegates.

How can I check my delegate if is still valid before trying to send it a message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there's a chance that the delegate will get released by the setter, then there's something wrong with your design. You should only set delegates on objects that have a shorter lifespan than the delegate itself. For example, setting a delegate on a subview/controller is fine, because the subview/controller has a shorter lifespan than the caller.

AFAIK, there is no reliable way to detect if an object has been released already.

Comment: To see if an object has been released completely - send a log message in either the `dealloc` or `finalize` methods of the class.

Comment: @Abizem: that won't help in this case. The question is whether you can detect if an object has been released (deallocated). I don't think that's possible at all without cooperation of the object itself.

Comment: I meant that the class sends the log messages when it's deallocated completely.

Comment: Abizern: That would be “cooperation of the [deallocated] object itself”.

Comment: It's fine to set a delegate that could have a shorter lifespan, you just have to make sure that the object delegated to sets the delegate to nil in its dealloc method.

Comment: @smorgan: Wouldn't that be too late? What if the delegate method is called right at the beginning of dealloc, before the line where you set the thing's delegate to nil? Then the object will still be deallocated, and the delegate method will still be called

Comment: That can only happen if you can get delegate callbacks on a different thread than you are deallocing the delegate. If you have multithreaded code where you are destroying things that are still in use by other threads you already have much bigger design flaws.

Answer (score 3):

What Apple means about not retaining delegates is that objects should not retain their delegates because they don't own them. These are only objects that handle messages.

That doesn't mean that you shouldn't retain delegates at all. The object that creates the delegate needs to own it. In the context of non-GC apps this means it should handle the retain and release cycle, and for GC apps, it means that the controller object keeps hold of a pointer to the delegate in an iVar.

without seeing some code or the error message, it is hard to find the root of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In a photoviewer application I'm using asynchronous http to load images; it happens that the user often dismisses the current view (referenced by my async http object through a delegate) before the http download completed causing a BAD_ACCESS when calling the view controller delegate method. I solved this by setting the .delegate to nil inside the dealloc block of the view controller

Comment: You may want to cancel and release the asynchronous HTTP download object instead, especially if your app is for the iPhone. The App Store reviewers don't take kindly to excessive bandwidth usage, such as when your app continues downloading an image after the user has already backed out of it. Ideally, save the partial file in the temporary-files directory, and resume the download if the user comes back to the image.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share my experience also, which is very similar to Nico's one.

I've been working with a modified example of LazyTablesCode, wich is an example that comes direcly from Apple and loads images in a UITableView asynchronously. Communication between the downloader and the view it's made via delegates.

In my code, I had the problem that sometimes the load of the image finishes when the form that should be called through the delegate has been released. I've been forced to add this piece of code inside the code of the viewController (dealloc method):

```
if (self.nsDictionaryWithObjectsDownloading != nil) {
    for (id theKey in self.nsDictionaryWithObjectsDownloading) {
        Myobj *downloader = [self.nsDictionaryWithObjectsDownloading objectForKey:theKey];
        downloader.delegate = nil;
    }
}
```

It seems that these lines are solving the problem. Anyway It would be very appreciated opinions about if it's a good solution or not or even about memory issues when doing downloader.delegate = nil;

Thanks and greetings,

Comment: I found nilling the delegate to be the best practical answer so far. However, Phillipe has some very good points.